# No unwrapping of boost::reference_wrapper in boost::in_place_factory

Tags: c++, boost, pass-by-reference

The following gives a compile error (`const boost::reference_wrapper<R>` has no member named `foo`). I'd expect `boost::in_place_factory` to automatically unwrap a `boost::reference_wrapper` though. As it is, I'd have to add unwrapping code to my own class `S` to support this use case.

Of course this only happens because the template parameter `T` is able to bind to `const boost::reference_wrapper<R>`. With a "normal" non-template constructor `S(R&)`, it would work fine.

```
#include <boost/optional.hpp>
#include <boost/ref.hpp>
#include <boost/utility/in_place_factory.hpp>

struct S
{
    template<typename T> S(T &t)
    {
        t.foo();
    }
};

struct R
{
    void foo(){}
};

int main() {
    boost::optional<S> s;
    R r;
    s = boost::in_place(boost::ref(r));
    return 0;
}
```

http://ideone.com/NjHsha

Is there a way to solve this without introducing a dependency to `boost::reference_wrapper` in `S`, ideally without touching `S` at all?